# filling sparse matrices efficiently matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I am working with a sparse matrix of very large size:

```
  U = sparse(a,b)   % a and b are very large
```

On the hand, there exists the cell Ind which has 'a' rows. In each row, there exists a 'variate' number of elements, e.g. :

```
  Ind{1} = [1 3 5 19 1000 1340]
  Ind{2} = [9 100 1500 1600 8000 b]
    ...
  Ind{a} = [3 5 6 90 1000 4300 5712 9480]
```

as could be seen the maximum index number in Ind{i} can be 'b'. For each of these index vector also exists a content matrix like 'c' :

```
 c = [2 3 1 6 3 5 1 3 4 1 2 ... 5]
```

Here is the question, for each element in Ind{i}, I want to fill the 'row = i' and the 'col=Ind{i}' with c(Ind{i}), i.e.

```
  for i = 1 : a
      U(i,Ind{i}) = c(Ind{i}) ;
  end
```

the problem is 'a' is very large and the loop takes long time to be computed. Any idea to avoid looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid the loop, but I do get a factor of 2-to-20 speed increase (I ranged `a` from 3 to 5,000 with `b` fixed at 10,000) by building three large vectors (two for row and column indices and one for values) and building the sparse matrix after the loop:

```
strides = cellfun(@numel,Ind);
n       = sum(strides);
I(n,1)  = 0;
J(n,1)  = 0;
S(n,1)  = 0;
bot     = 1;

for k = 1:a
    top  = bot + strides(k) - 1 ;
    mask = bot:top              ;
    %
    I(mask) = k         ;
    J(mask) = Ind{k}    ;
    S(mask) = c(Ind{k}) ;
    %
    bot = top + 1;
end
U = sparse(I,J,S,a,b);
```

This is the recommend usage of `sparse` because assignments to a sparse matrix are more costly than regular arrays.

Comment: U = sparse(I,J,S,a,b) is very interesting. There only one small issue left: assume  J=[50 300 12 9 50 12] . If we want to make the number of columns equal to max(J) it is nonsense. In this example, J need to be: J = [3 4 2 1 3 2]. If J is very large what function can do this transformation in your view?

Comment: @YAS "If we want to make the number of columns equal to max(J)" I don't understand this at all.  The final argument to `sparse` defines the maximum number of columns for the sparse matrix.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Minor note.  You can just do `strides = cellfun(@numel, Ind);`.  No need to wrap an anonymous function with `numel` because you can just call `numel` diirectly.

Comment: @rayryeng Huh.  I didn't realize there was a difference between the two forms.

Comment: Nope there isn't... Just less typing :) it's the code golf in me.

Comment: @rayryeng In terms of less typing, I don't mind and prefer the long form for explicitness.  But switching to the compact form does reduce run-time by about 20%+.  I wonder if some optimization exists for the direct form.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I agree with the explicitness.... but I didn't know that it reduces the run time by some 20+% if using `numel` directly... that's interesting and weird at the same time.

Comment: @rayryeng Ah. Apparently the explicit form attaches a workspace to the handle while the direct application of `@` is basically a pointer to a file.  I'll keep this is in mind in the future.

Comment: @TroyHaskin hm! How did you figure that out?  Good to know.